# Why does the rendering engine think I have nested section blocks?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css, razor

My asp.net razor (cshtml) file is failing to load; the YSOD says:

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Section blocks ("@section Header { ... }") cannot be nested.  Only one level of section blocks are allowed.    

Source Error:     

Line 239:}
Line 240:
Line 241:@section MainHead
Line 242:{
Line 243:    <link type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

Source File: /TLDReporter/Views/TLDCriteria/ReceiptCriteria.cshtml    Line: 241 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1008
```

The blocks in the file are:

```
@section ScriptContent
{
    // references to css and js, followed by jQuery code
}

@section MainHead
{
    // style/CSS block
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    // HTML
}
```

They all, as indicated above, have opening and closing braces and each one begins after the previous one has been closed off. So why does the rendering engine think I've got nested section blocks?

Comment: Do you have `@section Header` in your `@section MainHead`? It appears that isn't allowed.

Comment: No, I have not "@section Header" section; just the three listed in the post.

Comment: Must be somewhere, says so in the error `Section blocks ("@section Header { ... }")`

Comment: It would seem that way, but the only "section"s are those I enumerated above. And this page does not pull in a Layout Page, either.

Comment: have you checked to make sure you haven't got any stray brace `{}` characters in your sections?

Comment: Yes, but I'm going to have to go through it all again with a fine-toothed comb. I wish there was a Validator for cshtml pages, as there is for html and css and jQuery separately. The html is the problematic part, as it has Razorized code embedded within it, and the html validator would think the code was from Mars.

Comment: Use the brute force method. First, remove the entire `@Section Scriptcontent` (i.e. in your example, everything above `@Section MainHead`). Does the error go away? Then try to narrow it down.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, I'm going to just replace the entire HTML part of it, which uses tables, to "my way" of doing it (sans tables).

Comment: Prior to the great refactoring (86ing the table), I did find there was a missing "}" in a jQuery block - and adding it solved the problem. The easy fixes are almost the most irritating, I reckon because it's kind of embarrassing when you realize what a bonehead you've  been.

Comment: I'm getting that msg again, and all I did was replace "$("#submit_button").click(function () {" with "$("form").submit(function () {"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. the @section Header is not the section block the issue is with. navigate to the section that it is having a problem with and look at the closing tag for the section. More then likely it is not highlighted by the IDE like the beginning tag is. This is how mines looked:

```
@section scripts{
<script src="../../someFile.js"></script>
<!-- comment line -->
<script src="../../someOtherFile.js"></script>
<!-- more comments -->
<script src="../../lastFile.js"></script>    
}
```

It appears that it doesn't like the comments in my script section. It makes sense since the comment is in html vs. using the asp.net commenting style.  I copied and paste from another project and think about changing the code. Look for some type of formatting or coding issue with the content inside of your section that doesn't match up with